# Cardinality of a set of sequences of binary strings

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

> An “infinite increasing sequence of binary strings” is a series $w1$,
> $w2$, … of finite binary strings, such that for every number $i$,
> string $w_{i}$ is a prefix of $w_{i+1}$. For example, “101”,
> “$10100$”, “$101001$”, “$1010010111$”, … Let S be the set of infinite
> increasing sequences of binary strings. What is the cardinality of
> $S$?

This is a question from an exam, and I'm having trouble understanding what's going on there, let alone solve it, even without exam conditions. From my understanding S is a set of sequences $a_{1},a_{2},..$ such that $a_{i}$ is a sequence of some binary strings $w_{1}^{i},w_{2}^{i}...$ such that $w_{j}^{i}$ is a prefix of $w_{j+1}^{i}$. Now there is alot of stuff going on here and I'm not sure how to approach these type of questions.. where do I start? what should I look for?

Comment: If you think each finite string $w_i$ as a segment of a fixed infinite binary string, then the so called “infinite increasing sequence of binary strings” corresponds to an infinite binary string, which is a function $\mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$, together with an order-preserving function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}, i \mapsto \text{length of } w_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps look at it like this: if $w_i$ is an initial segment of $w_{i+1}$, let $u_i$ be the finite binary string such that $w_{i+1}=w_i^\frown u_i$ (and let $u_1=w_1$). Then we can convert the sequence $w_1,w_2,w_3,\dots$ to $u_1,u_2,u_3,\dots$. It's easy to see that this conversion is bijective. Note that the each $u_i$ could be *any finite binary string* and does not depend on the value of the previous $u_j$ for $j<i$.

Thus, instead of an infinite sequence of increasingly longer finite binary strings that extend each other, we just have an infinite sequence of arbitrary finite binary strings.

---

To solve the question, you need the answer to the following two questions:

- How many finite binary strings are there? Let's call this cardinality $X$
- If $S'$ is the set of sequences of length $\alpha$ of elements in $X$, what is the cardinality of $S'$?

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Your comment to my "answer" was correct, and fixing it leads to your answer. I deleted mine, +1 to you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to show $|S|\le 2^{\aleph_0}.$  Assume this is done.

So if we can find $T\subset S$ with $|T|=2^{\aleph_0}$ then $|S|=2^{\aleph_0}$.

Consider each $w_i$ as a member of $\Bbb N_0$ written in binary. Then $w_{i+1}=2^{k_i}w_i+n_i$ for some $k_i\in \Bbb N$ and some $n_i \in\Bbb N_0$ with $n_i<2^{k_i}.$

Let $B$ be the set of all countably infinite binary sequences. For any $b=(n_{i,b})_{i\in\Bbb N}\in B,$ take $w(b)=(w_{i,b})_{i\in\Bbb N}\in S$ where  the length of  $w_{i,b}$ (considered as a string) is $i$ for all $i\in \Bbb N$ and, when considered as numbers, $w_{1,b}=0$ and $w_{i+1,b}=2w_{i,b}+n_{i,b}$ for all $i\in \Bbb N.$

Let $T=\{w(b): b\in B\}$. If $b,b'$ are unequal members of $B$ then $w(b)\ne w(b').$ So $|T|=|B|=2^{\aleph_0}.$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $2^{\aleph_0}$.

**Some notation ahead:** For a positive integer number $n$, we denote the bold $\mathbf{n}$ the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. For two sets $A$ and $B$, we denote $B^A$ the set of all maps from $A$ to $B$.

**Remark:** a finite binary string can be viewed as a map $\mathbf{n} \to \mathbf{2}$ where $n$ is the length of the string in question. For example, the string $101$ can be viewed as the map $\mathbf{3} \to \mathbf{2}, 1 \mapsto 1, 2 \mapsto 0, 3 \mapsto 1$.

**Alternating the definition:** We now define the "infinite increasing sequence of binary strings" in the language of set and map: an *infinite increasing sequence of binary strings* is a pair of  map  $(w,l)$ where
$$
l: \mathbb{N}^+ \to \mathbb{N}^+ 
$$
and
$$
w: \mathbb{N}^+ \to \mathbf{2}
$$

To see why this defines the "infinite increasing sequence of binary strings", consider the following association: given such a pair of map $(w,l)$, we obtain a series of maps
$$
w_i: \mathbf{n_i} \to \mathbf{2}
$$
which is the restriction of $w$ to $\mathbf{n_i}$ where $i \in \mathbb{N}^+$ and $n_i = \sum_{j=1}^i l(j)$. It is easy that $(w_1,\ldots,w_i,\ldots)$ is an "infinite increasing sequence of binary strings" in the original sense. One checks that this association is actually a bijection.

**Evaluation of the cardinality:** By identifying $\mathbb{N}^+$ with $\mathbb{N}$, the original problem boils down to evaluate the cardinality of the Cartesian product set $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \times \mathbf{2}^\mathbb{N}$. It is well-know that each factor set is of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ hence the product set.

Comment: I don't see any justification in your answer to the claim that the answer is $\aleph_1$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila here I assume the continuum hypothesis, so $\aleph_1 = 2^{\aleph_0}$. As my answer shows, the set in question is equipotent to the set $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \times 2^N$ with cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: But why do you need to assume CH for this answer to make sense? (Except the first and last sentences.)

Comment: That isn't a big deal, if you don't agree with CH, just think the answer is $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: The point is that CH is not that commonly assumed throughout mathematics, even through set theory. Using it, **especially** without being explicit about it, can be misleading.